# How to find my questions for which I have not accepted an answer

Tags: feature-request, accepting, lists, search

I am looking for a way of listing, in first-come-first fashion, the questions for which I have not chosen one of the answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search), you can search for [`user:10827 hasaccepted:0 closed:0` sorted by "newest"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a10827%20hasaccepted%3a0%20closed%3a0). This searches TeX.SX for posts by [User 10827 (you)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10827/maesumi) that has no accepted answer (`hasaccepted:0`) and is not closed (`closed:0`), filtered according to the posted date. Currently there are 5 such questions (see below).

You can as well add the flag that eliminates non-answered ones (`answered:1`). The final search can be [`user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1 closed:0`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1+closed%3A0)

[image]

---

Another way of doing this would be through manual [sorting of your questions by newest first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10827/maesumi?tab=questions&sort=newest); this shows your posts as a timeline. Those that have accepted answers have a light-green blocked answer. Those without an accepted answer is left without a light-green block.

Of your current list of questions, I've marked those from the top 8 that do not have any accepted answers below:

[image]

They are:

- [How to add a favicon to a TeX/PDF file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59275/5764)
- [(Customizable) LaTeX equation editors for students](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58569/5764)
- [Which PDF/DVI viewers have spelling error or homonym detectors?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57321/5764)

Questions that are closed will look similar in its un-answered-ness.

Comment: Super Ninja Search FTW! `:)` A shortcut for searching `user:<ID>` when `<ID>` is you is to use the key `user:me` instead of the ID (I never remember my ID). `:)`