# How to find your own questions with unaccepted answers?

Tags: support, accepting, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find my questions for which I have not accepted an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2538/how-to-find-my-questions-for-which-i-have-not-accepted-an-answer)

I can't find an easy way to review all the questions which I have asked which a) have at least one answer and which b) I have not accepted an answer for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143432/163868 describes you can find them by searching. Use the search term `hasaccepted:0` to only find questions with no accepted answer, `answers:1` to only find questions with at least one answer and use `user:me` to only find posts by you, i.e. search for

```
hasaccepted:0 answers:1 user:me
```

You can also use a user id instead of `me`, such as `user:17049` for you. So the following search will also find your questions with no accepted answers  https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1+user%3A17049&submit=search.

Comment: That's the same as `user:me hasaccepted:0` in the search box, yes?

Comment: For reference, there is a list of such search options here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search

Comment: @JosephWright It is the same for Mohan but not for anyone else as `me` is indexical whereas a user id is not.

Comment: @JosephWright: the `answers:1' restricts it to things that have at least 1 answer. (Not exactly one, as it turns out.)